# n-type p-type intrinsic semiconductor

Tags: semiconductor-physics

If a material is simultaneously doped with acceptor (p-type defect) and also donor (n-type defect), with suitably adjusting the doping level, can the material be controlled as intrinsic type (or μF is located in the middle of bandgap)?

Answer (score 4):

Doping a semiconductor with both donors and acceptors is called compensation. As far as carrier statistics (and the position of the Fermi level) is concerned, you only need to consider the net doping concentration ($N_{D,\text{net}}=N_D-N_A$ if $N_D>N_A$, or $N_{A,\text{net}}=N_A-N_D$ if $N_A>N_D$), which plays the same role as the doping concentration in a non-compensated semiconductor. Yes, the semiconductor will be intrinsic if $N_D = N_A$.

There are also second-order effects caused by compensation, most importantly mobility degradation due to impurity scattering, and band gap narrowing. The first doesn't affect carrier statistics in a bulk semiconductor, and for most purposes the second requires quite high doping concentrations to have a major impact.